# getting no result in functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. Protein,PubMed and the third table ( protein_has_pubmed ) is joining these two tables.

I have written my sql code like this:

```
delimiter $$
create function ListOfPubMedIds(pr_id varchar(15)) 
returns varchar(500)
begin
Declare xx varchar(500);
select GROUP_CONCAT(pu.PubMedId) into xx
from protein p
join protein_has_pubmed pr on
p.UniprotKB_Accession=pr.Protein_UniprotKB_Accession
join pubmed pu on
pr.PubMed_P_id=pu.P_id
where   p.UniprotKB_Accession in('pr_id') ;
return xx;
end$$
delimiter ;  

select ListOfPubMedIds('P04637');
```

but it is not returning any value in output . It is just returning the column named as

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
+ ListOfPubMedIds('P04637') +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+...........................+
+...........................+
+...........................+
```

when I am running the below query:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(pu.PubMedId) 
from protein p
join protein_has_pubmed pr on
p.UniprotKB_Accession=pr.Protein_UniprotKB_Accession
join pubmed pu on
pr.PubMed_P_id=pu.P_id
where   p.UniprotKB_Accession in('P04637') ;
```

It is giving me the correct result like:

```
4006916,2946935,3894933,3025664,2905688,1915267,8316628,11058590,16131611,11023613
```

Again getting the same error for the below code:

```
delimiter $$
create function HTMLLink(E_id varchar(15),E_id_link varchar(200)) 
returns varchar(350)
begin
Declare xx varchar(350);
select concat('<html><a hreaf=', '"', 
          E_id_link, '"target="_blank">  <b>',
          E_id,'</b></html>') into xx
from disease d
where   d.EntryId=E_id and d.EntryIdLink=E_id_link;
return xx;
end$$
delimiter ;

select HTMLLink('P04637','http://pir0.georgetown.edu/cgi-bin/entry_p2p.pl?cui=C0278836') as HTMLLink;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to have a few misplaced quotes:

```
where   p.UniprotKB_Accession in('pr_id')
```

should be:

```
where   p.UniprotKB_Accession in(pr_id)
```

Comment: thanks..it worked...do you know any way so that the values should return separated by ' ; ' (semicolon) not by ' , ' (comma) ..

Comment: In your group_concat function add separator ';' :

GROUP_CONCAT(pu.PubMedId separator ';')

should do the trick

Comment: Hi Nobert......again getting the same result (no value in column) for the code I have added in the question at the last..

Comment: That one is a bit harder to see. Do you have an example without the function to check the result of the query? (PS. you have a typo in href "hreaf")

Comment: select concat('<html><a hreaf=', '"', EntryIdLink, '"target="_blank"><b>',EntryId,'</b></html>') from disease

Comment: Your query in the function has "where   d.EntryId=E_id and d.EntryIdLink=E_id_link" in it. Please check your data to see if you ask for valid record.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your parameter is not called properly in your WHERE CONDITION. you shouldn't enclosed it on singe quote ('). Second if you are using IN command your SELECT statement should be in PREPARED STATEMENT to include all values in your parameter because if you didn't use it only first value before the first comma will be in you're WHERE CLAUSE. Try my revised function below:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION ListOfPubMedIds (pr_id VARCHAR (15)) RETURNS VARCHAR (500) 
BEGIN
 DECLARE xx VARCHAR (500) ;
 SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pu.PubMedId) 
INTO xx
FROM protein p
JOIN protein_has_pubmed pr ON   p.UniprotKB_Accession=pr.Protein_UniprotKB_Accession
JOIN pubmed pu ON pr.PubMed_P_id=pu.P_id
WHERE p.UniprotKB_Accession IN(',pr_id,')') ;
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;
 EXECUTE stmt ;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt ;
 RETURN xx ;
END $$
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Please be reminded also to enclosed every value with single-qoute. Sample 'P04637','P04634','P04636'